# Prism.js TypeError: element.className is undefined

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, prism.js

I've an issue with prism.js, the syntax hightlighter.

It seems that i've all configured but no way, it doesn't want to work.

HTML code:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prism.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.6.0/themes/prism-okaidia.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/prism.js"></script>

  <h3>Code du script choisi</h3>
  <pre><code id="input" class="language-javascript"></code></pre>
```

Website: [e-toon.fr/labs](http://e-toon.fr/labs)

Comment: Ask me for further informations.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? The site you link is showing code being correctly highlighted on the left-hand side.